# Including element-specific javascript in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I like to keep my javascript out of views if possible, but I've found that difficult in certain situations.

Say I have a video partial that has corresponding javascript (using jplayer):

#### _video.haml

```
.video
  content_for :javascript/head
    / jplayer instance code here
```

One alternative I've thought is to hook into `.video` from within a separate js file and instantiate jplayer objects via that.

#### videos.coffee

```
$('.video').each
  # jplayer instance code here
```

My question is, what about pages where '.video' isn't found? Will it cause problems if I have lots of jquery finders that are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to check the length of .video and only run if it does exist

```
var $video = $('.video');
if(video.length !== 0){
     $('.video').each
     # jplayer instance code here
}
```

it checks the length of that jQuery object in the DOM

Comment: @Zenph did this answer your question? If i answered can you please mark it as answered :)